Ubuntu unable to join AD
I have setup an AD server in my private network. I can successfully join the domain from windows PCs. But when I try to join my ubuntu clients (ubuntu 23.04) I get errors that get me nowhere on google.
bp@legion:app (UM-200_usb) % sudo realm join -U -v Administrator sb.lan
 * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.sb.lan
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 172.19.0.2
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 192.168.1.100
 * Successfully discovered: sb.lan
Password for Administrator: 
 * Unconditionally checking packages
 * Resolving required packages
 * LANG=C /usr/sbin/adcli join --verbose --domain sb.lan --domain-realm SB.LAN --domain-controller 192.168.1.100 --login-type user --login-user Administrator --stdin-password
 * Using domain name: sb.lan
 * Calculated computer account name from fqdn: LEGION
 * Using domain realm: sb.lan
 * Sending NetLogon ping to domain controller: 192.168.1.100
 * Received NetLogon info from: dc.sb.lan
 * Wrote out krb5.conf snippet to /var/cache/realmd/adcli-krb5-2BPZfj/krb5.d/adcli-krb5-conf-EO27Dm
 ! Couldn't authenticate as: Administrator@SB.LAN: Preauthentication failed
adcli: couldn't connect to sb.lan domain: Couldn't authenticate as: Administrator@SB.LAN: Preauthentication failed
 ! Failed to join the domain
realm: Couldn't join realm: Failed to join the domain


chat gpt, and too many forums are pointing towards kerberos configuration. I am not even sure if I use kerberos. I am following the official ubuntu docs. Anyway, I don't have /etc/krb5.conf, nor do I know if I should...
so I've installed :
sudo apt install sssd-ad sssd-tools realmd adcli

I am sure that:

domain is correct
Administrator exists (I used the same username/password to join windows 10 client)
password is correct
this exact problem reproduces on three other ubuntu laptops (on 23.04 and 23.10)

Is there anybody who can shed some light on this? Am I doing something wrong?

Do user have right to join machines to the domain?

In a youtube video I found my answer
In my case the /etc/krb5.conf did not exist yet.
Creating it with the following contents solved the problem.
[libdefaults]
default_realm = SB.LAN
        rdns = false


